# CustomUser matching query does not exist allauth

Tags: django-allauth, django-custom-user, dj-rest-auth

this error happens when i login in using social auth that connect with customuser model .

/accounts/google/login/callback/ CustomUser matching query does not exist.
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
user_api.models.CustomUser.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.
[03/Apr/2023 04:43:51] "GET /accounts/google/login/callback/?state=hIP4XQIEu2T0&code=4%2F0AVHEtk7BhqZS4My4nw1gCkXyHmraxoHaFNZIg_s6Rht5bP7mK8nIhn2iw_2RDn1KmVi9iw&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&authuser=0&prompt=none HTTP/1.1" 500 107611

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
    
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime ,timedelta


""" set the subscription to end in 30 days"""
sub_expiration=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=30) 

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    subscription_date = models.DateTimeField(default=sub_expiration,null=True, blank=True)
    social_account= models.ForeignKey(SocialAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name='usersocial')
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        blank=True,
        related_name='customuser_set',
        related_query_name='customuser',
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        blank=True,
        related_name='customuser_set',
        related_query_name='customuser',
    )
    

  
 @property
    def auth_source(self):
        auth_source = self.social_account.provider
        return auth_source
        
 @property
    def auth_id(self):
        auth_id = self.social_account.uid
        return auth_id
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_api.CustomUser'
```

when I am using the default user, I did not get the error, another thing when I remove the social account the errors go away but I can not add the property that I need in my custom user.
thank you in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4WKr.png).